Why is EOF triggering on the last word instead of after trying to reget input?
So currently working on some exercises on I/O, my code basically takes a string from input and removes the vowels at input:
ExerciseClass.cpp:
NoVowelString& NoVowelString::operator>>(std::string& s) {
  while (!(Buffer >> s)) {
    if (Buffer.bad() || !(InputSource.good())) return *this;
    Buffer.clear();

    std::string vowelstring;
    InputSource >> vowelstring;

    for (int i = 0; i < vowelstring.size(); i++) {
      if (!CaseSensitive) vowelstring[i] = tolower(vowelstring[i]);
      if (IsVowel(tolower(vowelstring[i]))) { 
        vowelstring.erase(vowelstring.begin() + i);
        i = -1;
      }
    }
    Buffer.str(vowelstring);
   }
  return *this;
}

NoVowelString::operator bool() {
return  !(InputSource.fail() || InputSource.bad()) && InputSource.good();
}

Main.cpp:
while (NoVowelStrings >> s) {
  ProcessedInput.push_back(s);
}

now the thing is that it works perfectly when dealing with input from keyboard(cin istream) but for files it skips the last word, that's because Inputsource.eof() sets off after reading the last word, without having to read after it, so in main s gets the correct value but it doesn't get into the vector, tried searching a bit online but to no avail. My guess is that something in the function that converts the stream to bool is wrong but I can't figure out what.
Debugged the code, after putting an if(InputSource.eof()) std::cout << "bad" after the InputSource >> vowelstring I found that it always went eof right after getting the last string, and, from what I know, the input stream should output eof trying to read after the last string. Even though i dont know for certain what cause it to fail i suppose it's the eof flag making the boolean return false.

The last line in the file doesn't finish with \n

The code in the question is both too little and too much, Post the smallest code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. Most of the processing inside that operator>> is irrelevant; main.cpp is inadequate.

That operator bool looks funky. By DeMorgan's theorem, !(InputSource.fail() || InputSource.bad()) is equivalent to !InputSource.fail() && !InputSource.bad(), so that operator returns !InputSource.fail() && !InputSource.bad() && InputSource.good(). That seems to test pretty much the same thing in three different ways (assuming that InputSource, which has not been defined, is what it's name suggests).

eof() will be true after you have tried to read past the end of file. Whether that happens when you read the last string or whether it happens after you have read the last string depends on whether the file ends with whitespace or not. In other words using eof() as any kind of test for whether you have finished reading is incorrect. The code above is way more complex than it needs to be while (InputSource >> vowelString) ... is the way to go.

Thanks for the suggestions, I used as inspiration programming, principles and practices by Stroupstroup, for the bool i tought that was pretty funky too, should i just go with a check on InputSource.good()?  Probably will implement the while(InputSource >> vowelstring suggestion as it seems much simpler. As for the code posted the other code in main just opens the file and constructs NoVowelString, now that i know why it sends eof ill try finding some ways to debug it thanks!

adding more thought to it I dont know if the InputSource >> vowelstring works in my case as the operator needs to get only one string but the code certainly can be made simpler
